# explicit for actors taking more than one argument

Tags: c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class P
{
public:
    P(int a, int b)
    {
        cout << "P(int a, int b)" << endl;
    }
    P(initializer_list<int>)
    {
        cout << "P(initializer_list<int>)" << endl;
    }
     explicit P(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        cout << "explicit P(int a, int b, int c)" << endl;
    }
};
void fp(const P&)
{

}
int main(){
    P p1(77, 5); //P(int a, int b)
    P p2{ 77,5 }; //P(initializer_list<int>)

    P p3{ 77,5,42 };//P(initializer_list<int>)

    P p4 = { 77, 5};//P(initializer_list<int>)
    P p5 = { 77,5,42 };//P(initializer_list<int>)
    P p6(77, 5, 42);//explicit P(int a, int b, int c)

    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    fp({ 47,11 });//P(initializer_list<int>)
    fp({ 47,11,3 });//P(initializer_list<int>)
    fp(P{ 47,11 });//P(initializer_list<int>)
    fp(P{ 47,11,3 });//P(initializer_list<int>)
    cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
    P p11{ 77,5,42,500 };//P(initializer_list<int>)
    P p12 = { 77, 5, 42, 500 };//P(initializer_list<int>)
    P p13{ 10 };//P(initializer_list<int>)

    cout<<__cplusplus<<endl;//201103
    return 0;
}
```

P p5 = { 77,5,42 };

fp({ 47,11,3 });

These two lines of code would theoratically give an error, but I compiled it, and the comments above are the results of the run.   My compiler version is gcc8.1.0

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is there no error

Answer (score 2):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

> Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
> All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument,
> or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default
> values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a
> single argument of type std::initializer_list
>
> If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T
> participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that
> consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction
> that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage
> produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a
> copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple
> copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).

So the init list constructor has precedence over the explicit 3 argument constructor.

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to avoid overloading an initializer_list constructor with any other constructors because there are lot of possible cases that don't work the way you might expect them too.  See Effective Modern C++ by Scott Meyers for details.